# Getting the shellscript to display a chosen file extension

Tags: shell-script, files

I'm new to this with shellscript and Linux and now I'm stuck. I shall write a simple program that allows me to search for andy file extension I want and then display how many of them there are.
I've been searching the net and read the book I've got but I just can't figure it out.

This is what I got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Program to search for how many of specific file extension there is in this directory.

echo "Write the file extension you want to search for:"
read n

for n in `ls *.txt` ; do
  echo $n
done
```

I'm suppose to use a for loop.

How do I continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already `find` is usually the correct tool when handling files. It can however be perfectly OK.

You can skip this part of `printf` if you want, only include it as a *bonus* :P

One thing that you also can start using is `printf`. It is generally a better option then `echo`. In its simplest form you have:

```
printf "Some text\n"
```

where `\n` is new-line. If you want to print some variable you can use the special symbol `%s` (for string):

```
printf "Name is %s \n" "$name"
              |           |
              |           +---- value
              +---------------- format string

printf "Name is %s city is %s \n" "$name" "$city"
              |                      |       |
              |                      +-------+----- values
              +------------------------------------ format string
```

There are other symbols you can use, such as `%d` (for digit). You can also use other special characters such as `\t` (tab).

For you code it is generally better to use the newer `$(cmd)` instead of ``cmd`. In your code that would be:

```
$(ls *.txt)
```

Next thing to look at is the `for` loop. Your statement

```
for n in `ls *.txt`; do
```

does not do what you think. Here `n` is treated as a variable name to which the result of `ls *.txt` is assigned. If you have the files:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

The execution of the code would expand to:

```
for n in a.txt b.txt c.txt; do
```

That is: for each iteration `n` is set to the next file name. You end up with:

```
n=a.txt  (first loop)
n=b.txt  (second loop)
n=c.txt  (last loop)
```

If we collect this together we can for example write something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Write the file extension you want to search for: "
read ext

printf "Searching for files with extension '%s'\n" "$ext"

for file in *"$ext"; do
    printf "File: %s\n" "$file"
done
```

Or you can simply say:

```
ls *"$ext"
```

Note that the asterisk is *outside* the quotes. Else it won't expand.

Comment: Also, using `for n in $(ls *.txt)` is unnecessary, just use `for n in *.txt`. `ls` is just repeating the list of files that the shell already expanded. Not that you need a loop in this case...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Write the file extension you want to search for:"
read n
find $1 -iname "*.$n" -print
```

usage :

```
./myscript.sh mypath
```

Output is :

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen/test# ./myscript.sh /home/mohsen
Write the file extension you want to search for:sh
/home/mohsen/Downloads/binary files/apt-fast_aria2c.sh
/home/mohsen/Downloads/binary files/apt-fast.sh
/home/mohsen/Downloads/binary files/toggle_touchpad.sh
/home/mohsen/Downloads/binary files/nvidia-versions.sh
/home/mohsen/Downloads/R/x/PacketTracer601/set_ptenv.sh
/home/mohsen/codes/IraninCalendar/test/jcal-master/sources/ltmain.sh
/home/mohsen/codes/IraninCalendar/test/jcal-master/sources/autogen.sh
^C
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/find.1posix). Something like:

```
echo "Write the file extension you want to search for:"
read n
find . -name "*.$n"
```

Anyway, what you probably intended to do was:

```
for i in *."$n"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Otherwise, you're not using the value of `n` (instead using the fixed extension `txt`), and overwriting the read value of `n` in the `for` loop,

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that it is suppose to be a for-loop.  So I wrote this and it works, but it only gives me the output: "*.sh" when for example searching for file extension sh.

Comment: @Anileve That happens when no matches were found. `*.sh` remains unexpanded if there are no files matching that pattern.

Comment: Ah of course =)

Answer (score 0):

A single line command:

```
echo "Enter file extension:"  
for f in `find <some_path> -name "*$(read n; echo $n)"` ; do echo $f ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

> search for andy file extension I want and then display how many of
>   them there are

You don't need a loop for that at all. Assuming there are no newline characters inside file names you can write

```
wc -l < <(ls *."$n")
```